# Correct way to compare two pointees to use in std algorithms

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I am playing with boost::range and boost::lambda with following example to compare two numbers and get the element out which has same number.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/range/algorithm/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/compare_pointees.hpp>

template <class Range, class Predicate> 
boost::optional<typename boost::range_value<Range>::type> 
search_for(const Range& r, Predicate pred) 
{ 
      BOOST_AUTO (it, boost::find_if(r, pred));
      if (it == boost::end(r)) 
          return boost::none; 
      return *it; 
 } 


 int main() 
 { 
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  int d = 3;

  std::vector<int*> m = {&a, &b, &c}; 
  if (boost::optional<int*> number = 
  search_for(m, boost::equal_pointees(???, &d))) { 
       std::cout << "found:" << (*number.get()) << std::endl; 
  } 
  else { 
       std::cout << "not found" << std::endl; 
   } 
}
```

What should I use  for `???` above in `search_for` function?

I believe it could be very simple but don't know how to do it. I can use the boost::bind or std::bind2d, etc to compare but was thinking if there is any elegant way to do it.  Also, this code sample could be restructured to much simpler one but I am just learning.

Comment: Are you limited to C++03?

Comment: Yes. That's why BOOST_AUTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With boost::lambda, it looks like this:

```
namespace ll = boost::lambda;

search_for(m, *ll::_1 == d)
```

Which is far less complicated than taking a pointer to `d` just so you can use `equal_pointees`.

Comment: If I using an object instead of plain numbers in above example, can I so something like ll::_1.myMethod() == d.myMethod() ? I think I can't do that. Is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: You can use bind: `ll::bind(&MyClass::myMethod, ll::_1) == d.myMethod()`. This gets annoying when `myMethod` is overloaded since you need an explicit cast to the right member pointer type.